# Using transition maps as a comparison tool between charts on a manifold.

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

In the wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart_%28topology%29#Transition_maps we read

> A transition map provides a way of comparing two charts of an atlas. To make this comparison, we consider the composition of one chart with the inverse of the other.

I don't understand the word **comparison** in this context. I mean we have two homeomorphisms and we take their composition to get a homeomorphism from a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ to a subset of $\mathbb R^n$.. Can someone please explain in what sense this is a comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get homeomorphisms of different "quality" : the lowest form of compatibility happens when the transition function is a mere homeomorphism, but the transition function may be more regular, of class $C^1, C^2,\dots, C^{\infty}$, analytical or even rational.

The regularity of the transition functions measures how well attuned the charts are with respect to one another.

Comment: Ok so comparision here is in the sense of how much compatible the charts are in the same atlas.. and this has to be done for all charts that intersect, and if much of these charts are regular more than another differential structure on the same manifold we decide that this differential structure is more suitable to work with, is my understanding correct.. So in conclusion, transition maps are introduced to mesure the regularity of the differential structure chosen on the manifold..

Comment: That's right : if you have an atlas of charts of $M$, you look at all the different transition functions and their regularity and then declare : "this is a $C^{\infty}$ atlas!" for instance. I seem to remember theorems in Hirsch's *Differential topology* to the effect that any manifold with a $C^2$ structure automatically has a $C^{\infty}$ structure.